# Implicit Constructor Used Automatically (and Incorrectly)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am working on some code (a variant of the OpenJDK 8 VM, if you're wondering) that is trying to instantiate a C++ class called `InterpreterMacroAssembler` using this code:

```
// interpreter.hpp
CodeletMark(InterpreterMacroAssembler*& masm,
            const char* description,
            Bytecodes::Code bytecode = Bytecodes::_illegal):
    _clet((InterpreterCodelet*)AbstractInterpreter::code()->request(codelet_size())),
    _cb(_clet->code_begin(), _clet->code_size())
{
    // request all space (add some slack for Codelet data)
    assert (_clet != NULL, "we checked not enough space already");

    // initialize Codelet attributes
    _clet->initialize(description, bytecode);
    // create assembler for code generation
    masm  = new InterpreterMacroAssembler(&_cb);
    _masm = &masm;
}

// macroAssembler_x86.hpp
MacroAssembler(CodeBuffer* code) : Assembler(code) {}
```

The problem is, the compiler is emitting a [C2664](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5b150wd.aspx) error, because it thinks I'm trying to invoke the implicitly created copy constructor (with a signature of `ImplicitMacroAssembler(const ImplicitMacroAssembler &)`) instead, and is throwing a type-mismatch error because I am not passing an object of the same type. I have verified (through use of a judiciously placed `#pragma message`) that the correct constructor is being seen by the compiler, but it is not being used for some reason. Is there any reason why the C++ compiler would prefer an implicitly generated copy constructor over an explicitly written (but not `explicit`, in the C++ keyword sense) user-defined constructor?

Changing the code above to store the new `InterpreterMacroAssembler` instance in a local variable (I'm calling it `masm2`), and then putting `masm2` into the `masm` and `_masm` variables in the same fashion as above, doesn't change anything.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Release Preview, with `cl` version 19.00.22816, if that helps anything.

Comment: It would be more useful if you could provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The code above won't compile, since you are not allowed to declare a reference variable uninitialized like that. By "parameter", I take it you mean a function parameter, but it is curious why your example does not just provide the correct illustration instead of a confusing and misleading one.

Comment: include the exact error message too

Comment: Does the class `InterpreterMacroAssembler` have a constructor with the signature `InterpreterMacroAssembler(CodeBuffer *)` visible from the code calling it?

Answer (score 1):

From your textual description of the problem:

```
void foo (InterpreterMacroAssember*& masm) {
    //... do something with masm
}

//...
CodeBuffer _cb;
foo(new InterpreterMacroAssembler(&_cb));
```

This would fail since you are taking the reference of a temporary pointer.

You misinterpreted the error code. From the documentation page you cited:

> `'function' : cannot convert parameter number from 'type1' to 'type2'`
>   This parameter conversion problem might happen if an instance of a class is created and an implicit conversion is attempted on a constructor marked with the explicit keyword. For more information about explicit conversions, see Conversions.
>   **If a temporary object is passed to a function that takes a reference to an object as a parameter, that reference must be a const reference.**

You likely hit the problem explained in the second paragraph, which I highlighted.

To fix, make the parameter a `const` reference. Since it is a pointer parameter, the `const` keyword needs to sit between the reference and pointer type indicators.

```
void foo (InterpreterMacroAssember* const & masm) {  //...
```

But, it is a little silly to take the reference in the first place. Unless the Java interface requires it, it is more straightforward to change the function to just take a pointer parameter.

```
void foo (InterpreterMacroAssember* masm) {  //...
```